# What should I call the troops in my world where the US military consolidated into a single, unified force?

Tags: society, warfare, weapons, military, military-defense

So basically, for some backstory, rising sea levels and a viral pandemic known as the Black Plague both killed off billions of people in 2015. During that time, due to the collapse of every country and modern civilization as a whole, the skeletal remains of the US Government retreated to the Peak Eight National Command Complex (PENCCOM), the (fictional) superbunker-fortress that was built to house the entire US Government and up to over 15,000 people with enough resources and supplies to last over 10-15 years and with enough weapons and ammo to arm a decent size army to invade a small country.

Anyway, the US military consolidated into a single, unified force for the sake of practicality and convenience since in the bunker, the vast majority of military personnel in the bunker were made up of soldiers and Marines. This new military force became the ***United States National Garrison***, with the US National Garrison having the training, discipline, esprit de corps, and lethality of the Marine Corps as well as the funding and equipment of the Army. The National Garrison also has a new uniform, which is basically just the woodland MARPAT Utilities uniform of the Marine Corps but in a much darker shade of green and brown.

So what should I call the troops who make up the US National Garrison? In passing, I refer to them as “the troops” and I’ve toyed around with calling them “troopers” but I don’t know, “trooper”/“troopers” sounds odd. I don’t want to just call them “soldiers” since that sounds too generic and Army-centric (same reason why I won’t call them “Marines” since then it’d pretty much be the Marine Corps).

Comment: shouldn't the plague have a unique name?

Answer (score 1):

I, personally would call them "Soldiers".  It translates well, is a universally recognized role, and leaves room for what *kind* of 'soldier', if further delinations are needed.